# WSO2 Identity Server 4 SAML metedata

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0

I have wso2 identity server up and running on localhost:9443.
I've created .net application as a service provider. My app uses OIOSAML.NET framework.
I need wso2 ids metadata in SAML-format. It' should be something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<q1:EntityDescriptor entityID="http://wso:9443/" ID="ide17674a8a4ca424da09d05939a841485" xmlns:q1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI="#ide17674a8a4ca424da09d05939a841485"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>yNQMi2eKXcIMbbHgd9pkMR6NrQk=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>WxQRp4EZ5AVSsLjqt6jeiqIs2b05Uh8DeiwgmUxc8XnuAVqVvsjhqyzFONKNC56GnmnZSOtO2l8W8hIDw3pNhQhDa6iEdXQHE4flGFZTUlUCL3M5Owc/BN3MMv4dJqMvumMszz79QsTeTAuI779T3APytPOfB92V0+Rw3PrMMX8=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>MIIB0TCCATqgAwIBAgIQE0QKzPxrX51LbIQIblakJjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAUMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlsb2NhbGhvc3QwHhcNMTIxMTIxMTE0NjUwWhcNMTcxMTIxMDAwMDAwWjAUMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlsb2NhbGhvc3QwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAL97SjGhJBcdoZ2Ug+1KWFZJPQVt7nR6Dxpi1EGEWM6/l51rqnEZXRtMbysnYipykzWfh7lzi4BYkwBXf+5rtp7q8WPA0QIWLnbDMhoOFFP41nPOYU0SSKJzbxOrTUCK0sRcMrksClONEgakRi/fYlSfzJb6t9morqL4E9bi+8qtAgMBAAGjJDAiMAsGA1UdDwQEAwIEsDATBgNVHSUEDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAO3TS3Z/frP3Kul34Ehiq0fLcStiKxQqZ2K5qkT1ajo6/sYF9UB/3k69sayjqKueCy/YqGFxuTse0v72+OgoeN9vlHXsxOt0jZ4W0u58RSf52OoEu8P9lq182YSB1X6A6U+oWTXZsXstWWmV/p0y+vsjBjTS0Mk7BXxkdolqDSiA==</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature>
  <q1:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <q1:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <X509Data>
          <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
    </q1:KeyDescriptor>
    <q1:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <X509Data>
          <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
    </q1:KeyDescriptor>
    <q1:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://wso:9443/samlsso" />
    <q1:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://wso:9443/samlsso" />
    <Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.3" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" />
    <Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" />
    <Attribute Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.10" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" />
    <Attribute Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.8" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" />
    <Attribute Name="dk:gov:saml:attribute:CvrNumberIdentifier" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" />
    <Attribute Name="urn:dk:oes:2009-10:Xform:attribute:Role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" />
  </q1:IDPSSODescriptor>
</q1:EntityDescriptor>
```

Is there any way to export this metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this reply is too late. But thought of sharing this answer since this may be helpful to somebody else who is searching the same metadata file of WSO2 Identity Server.

As of now with WSO2 IS 4.5.0, we do not have a mechanism to generate the metadata file. But you can make it manually. Given below is a metadata file of that manner which is prepared manually.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" validUntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z">
   <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
       <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
         <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE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=</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
     <md:SingleLogoutService 
           Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" 
           Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" 
           ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>

     <md:SingleSignOnService 
           Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
           Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>

     <md:SingleSignOnService
            Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
            Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```